# How to delete the SQL history records in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When clicked the 'View -> SQL History' in the Oracle SQL Developer, there will be a small flat window popped up and placed at the end of the whole window. And in this flat window, all my recent queries that have been executed are displayed there. How can I delete these SQL history records in this flat window? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have just observed that there is a `clear history` button available which can be used to either delete specific query by selecting one or all by selecting all using `ctrl+A`.

[image]

P.S. I didn't try to delete or validate it as I want to keep my history.

Comment: select all the records, ctrl/cmd+A, then click that button. Then say 'yes' to deleting your entire history.

Answer (score 1):

Each "history query" is saved as an XML file. It is located (on MS Windows) in a (hidden - set the Explorer to view hidden files!) folder whose name is e.g.

```
C:\Users\littlefoot\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\SqlHistory
```

Go in there and delete its contents.